# Why can't CakePHP bake connect to MySQL running under EasyPHP on Windows Vista Ultimate?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, easyphp, cakephp-1.2

I have [CakePHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) (cake_1.2.2.8120) and [EasyPHP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyPHP) (3.0) installed on [Windows Vista Ultimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_editions#Editions_for_personal_computers). I followed the "baking" tutorials online and successfully set the database connection with the "cake bake" command from the CLI.

I baked the controller for my "Users" table using the "php cake.php bake controller Users" command - worked fine. However, when I tried baking the view similarly, I got this message:

> ```
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\Web\EasyPHP
> ```

\www\cake\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 374'

Also, the MySQL module is enabled for PHP on the [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) page (web), but I can't find it in the CLI (using "php -m" from the command line) even though I've uncommented the "extension=php_mysql.dll" line in the php.ini file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you had a PHP installation without a compiled MySQL extension.

Comment: Yep, seems that EasyPHP doesn't provide the compiled MySQL for the CLI. XAMPP does that without any extra steps, just installation. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I think that the correct answer is not the one that points to change your software, but the one that points why there is the problem, ie, the answer from @andrej. That is the solution to the problem. In common PHP usage, there is a php.ini for Apache (web usage) and another one for the CLI (command line interface). So EasyPHP has the Apache one, but not the one for CLI. You must make a copy from the php.ini in the apache folder to the php folder for use in CLI. Thanks Andrej.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) which has Apache with the MySQL and PHP modules setup and working together, as well at the MySQL and command-line versions. It just unzips to any directory, so it won't mess up any other Apache installs you have. Just be careful of any port conflicts between the different installations.

*[Download XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)*

Comment: Thanks, man .. it's was the silly EasyPHP!
Now all's great (Y)

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of the problem is that in EasyPHP 5.3 there isn't any *php.ini* file in the *php* folder.

Copy `php.ini` from `EasyPHP5.3\apache` to `EasyPHP5.3\php` to solve this nasty issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know EasyPHP, but it seems to be Apache-based. Check if you're using a Apache-module for the MySQL connection, as this will not work in CLI.

Comment: Thx for the reply, but would you mind telling me how could I know that? I'm still new to those stuff :$ :)

Comment: EasyPHP is Windows-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the *apache/php.ini* file to *php/php.ini*.