# How can I find the php.ini file used by the command line?

Tags: php, easyphp

I need to enable *pdo_mysql* in my [EasyPHP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyPHP) environment, so I went to the *php.ini* file and uncommented the following line:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Unfortunately I still have the same problem.
I'm using the CLI so I suppose I need to locate the *php.ini* file used by the CLI. How can I find it?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8684609/632951

Comment: @sjas It is not the wrong, it is correct and let you know the path of the loaded php.ini in the cli.

Comment: EasyPHP (probably) implies [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). Perhaps tag it as such?

Comment: [Some context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828899/why-cant-cakephp-bake-connect-to-mysql-running-under-easyphp-on-windows-vista-u/1961355#1961355): *"The root cause of the problem is that in EasyPHP 5.3 there isn't any* ***php.ini*** *file in the* ***php*** *folder.*

Answer (score 1118, accepted):

Just run `php --ini` and look for *Loaded Configuration File* in the output for the location of `php.ini` used by your CLI.

Comment: @BradFJacobs why use grep when this is now cross-platform?

Comment: But doesn't this just show you the one that is loaded when using PHP via the CLI (because you are running the command from that).

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea: which is exactly what the question is about. See? It does state so even in the title: How to find the php.ini file used by the _command line_?

Comment: this is not my answer...in my case I type  `sudo find / -iname php.ini` and it founds `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` the right place of the right php.ini config file of my machine that it wasn't found by `php --ini` or `php -i | grep php.ini` (both found `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`)

Comment: @NineCattoRules if your cli php uses Apache's php.ini something is wrong with your setup

Comment: maybe it's because I've recently upgrade PHP to 7 from 5.5.9 ...where should I check my setup? Everything works as usual

Comment: ...also check this out http://askubuntu.com/a/356990/413592 I don't think there's something wrong with my setup

Comment: That answer says the same as me. There's a separate php.ini for CLI and a separate one for Apache.

Comment: A million files are displayed, would be nice to add a sentence fragment explaining which one is the CLI one.

Comment: @Mchl: I have shamelessly edited your answer to include the informative not to look for `Loaded Configuration File` in output :)

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: thank you. It's been so long time ago sine I worked with PHP I don't even recall if the output from `php --ini` was always this way, or it has changed since my answer.

Comment: It is empty in my case. Please can you advise.
# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini

Comment: @DulithaKumarasiri just create your own `php.ini` file, if you really need to change any setting. What happened is that your Docker container is merely using the reasonable defaults set by the PHP core developer team; you'd only need to _create_ a `php.ini` **if and only if** you need to _change_ a setting.

Comment: this only shows the location of the cli's php.ini file. the apach2 php.ini file is what most people usually look for and its location is `../apache2/php.ini` relatively

Comment: Thank you for this comment @Meilech. If you read the question though it specifically asks about CLI's php.ini.

Answer (score 403):

You can get a full `phpinfo()` using:

```
php -i
```

And, in there, there is the `php.ini` file used:

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

On Windows, use [`find`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/find.php) instead:

```
php -i | find/i"configuration file"
```

Comment: I did that but the weird thing is that it's pointing me the C:\WINDOWS path. And I didn't find it there?

Comment: The name of the file is still: php.ini right? Or something starting with php at least?

Comment: Then this php instance used no php.ini at all but the default values. The `Configuration File` line of phpinfo() shows the last place where php looked for an ini file. That can either be the place where it found such a file or the last option which happens to be %SYSTEMROOT% on windows.

Comment: @pascal: `php -i | find "Configuration file"` should work on Windows. Definitely not as powerful as grep, but `find` will do basic string searching for you. Of course, if php -i dumps its output to stderr, you're probably SOL.

Comment: `find` is case-sensitive by default, so it has to be perfect (`php -i | find "Configuration File"`) or made case-insensitive (`php -i | find /i "Configuration file"` - note the `/i` flag).

Comment: @deizel: thanks for the tip, you were right, it only works with the `/i` switch or you have to type in the exact string - and thanks for Marc B too for mentioning `find`. I edited the original post according to your comments.

Comment: Consider adding `php --ini` as an alternative; available since PHP 5.2.3 :)

Comment: PHP looks for config in 7 places as outlined here: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php.  If you are getting a pointer to C:\Windows with php --ini, do this to fix it:  click my computer->system properties->advanced system settings->environment variables->new...(system variable).  Name the key: PHPRC and set the value to the full path to your php.ini file.  Open a new console and enter php --ini again.  Your config should be loaded.

Comment: Nobody mentioned, that it's possible to take that value from script by calling [php_ini_loaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) and when needed [php_ini_scanned_files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php)

Comment: Just another side note: `grep` *is* available on windows: http://i.imgur.com/KP5MJRV.png

Comment: Works flawlessly for me. If the default "Configuration File" was not changed, you shouldn't worry about case-sensitivity. php --ini is a nice alternative for PHP 5.2.3+ versions.

Comment: Please notice that this could be very misleading if you have both php-cli install and another php which interacts with the webserver. Just running php -i from the command-line will most probably return the php.ini for the php-cli and not the one for the webserver.

Comment: On OSX Mavericks, running:

    $ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'

Returned:

    Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
    Loaded Configuration File:         (none)

In the `/etc/` directory was:

    php.ini.default

(as well as `php-fpm.conf.default`)

I was able to copy `php.ini.default` to `php.ini`, add `date.timezone = "US/Central"` to the top (right below `[php]`), and the problem is solved. At least the error message is gone.

Comment: In what environment on Windows? [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants)? Can you add something about this to your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Sample output on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) and [a LAMP equivalent](https://www.osradar.com/install-lamp-ubuntu-20-04/) (Apache, MariaDB, and PHP) - PHP 7.4.3: `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`

Answer (score 20):

You can use [get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path')](http://de.php.net/get_cfg_var) for that:

> To check whether the system is using a configuration file, try retrieving the value of the cfg_file_path configuration setting. If this is available, a configuration file is being used.

Unlike phpinfo() it will tell if it didn't find/use a php.ini at all.

```
var_dump( get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path') );
```

And you can simply [*set* the location of the php.ini](http://docs.php.net/configuration.file). You're using the command line version, so using the `-c` parameter you can specify the location for this particular run, e.g.

```
php -c /home/me/php.ini -f /home/me/test.php
```

Comment: Is it a permanent change or not? Can you be explicit about this in your answer?

Answer (score 19):

Run `php --ini` in your terminal, and you'll get all details about ini files:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php.d/bcmath.ini,
/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dba.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/imap.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/posix.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/ssh2.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

For more, use helping command `php --help`. It'll display all the possible options.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes things aren't always as they seem when in comes to configuration files in general. So here I'm applying my usual methods for exploring what files are opened by a process.

I use a very powerful and useful command-line program called [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to show me what's really going on behind my back!

```
$ strace -o strace.log php --version
$ grep php.ini strace.log
```

Strace digs out kernel (system) calls that your program makes and dumps the output into the file specified by `-o`.

It's easy to use [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to search for occurrences of file *php.ini* in this log. It's pretty obvious looking at the following typical response to see what is going on.

```
open("/usr/bin/php.ini", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/php.ini", O_RDONLY)          = 3
lstat("/etc/php.ini", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=69105, ...}) = 0
```

Comment: `php -i` gave me incorrect results, but this one is perfectly fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you want all the configuration files loaded, this is will tell you:

```
php -i | grep "\.ini"
```

Some systems load things from more than one ini file. On my Ubuntu system, it looks like this:

```
php -i | grep "\.ini"
```

#### Output

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need to pass it to another app, you can do something like:

```
php --ini | grep Loaded | cut -d" " -f12
```

returns the path only. `php -c $(php --ini | grep Loaded | cut -d" " -f12)` will pass in the config file (useful for `fpm`)

Answer (score 7):

On [OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks), running:

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Returned:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
```

In the `/etc/` directory was:

```
php.ini.default
```

(as well as `php-fpm.conf.default`)

I was able to copy `php.ini.default` to `php.ini`, add `date.timezone = "US/Central"` to the top (right below `[php]`), and the problem is solved.

(At least the error message is gone.)

Comment: Indeed, macOS (and OSX before it) never ships a `php.ini` file and relies on the PHP developers to have made sensible default choices (which is usually the case). But if you need to _change_ any setting, you have to do exactly what you've described. This actually saves a lot of time, since most users will never need to 'fix' their `php.ini` files...

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way *nowadays* is to use PHP configure:

```
php-config --ini-dir
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
```

---

There's more you can find there. The `--help` sub command (macOS local install):

```
php-config --help
```

Output:

```
Usage: /usr/local/bin/php-config [OPTION]
Options:
  --prefixUsage: /usr/local/bin/php-config [OPTION]
Options:
  --prefix            [/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11]
  --includes          [-I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php - …ETC…]
  --ldflags           [ -L/usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.18.2/lib -…ETC…]
  --libs              [ -ltidy -largon2 …ETC… ]
  --extension-dir     [/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/pecl/20190902]
  --include-dir       [/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php]
  --man-dir           [/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/share/man]
  --php-binary        [/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/bin/php]
  --php-sapis         [ apache2handler cli fpm phpdbg cgi]
  --ini-path          [/usr/local/etc/php/7.4]
  --ini-dir           [/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d]
  --configure-options [--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11 --…ETC…]
  --version           [7.4.11]
  --vernum            [70411]
```

Comment: Does that work for EasyPHP? It is Windows-specific.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have no idea what _EasyPHP_ is. The `php-config` command is distro and PHP version specific.+

Answer (score 4):

Try this if it could help you all:

```
find / -type f -name "php.ini"
```

This will output all files named `php.ini`.

Find out which one you're using, usually `apache2/php.ini`

Comment: This does not work if there is no php.ini file (some docker containers). Therefor the accepted answer is better suited.

Comment: No. `apache2/php.ini` is usually not used by CLI

Answer (score 3):

From what I remember when I used to use EasyPHP, the php.ini file is either in `C:\Windows\` or `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: Right it's telling me C:\WINDOWS. But I didn't find it there seriously!

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP uses different `php.ini` paths for HTTP(S) and CLI (console command line) mode, easiest way is to find out really loaded `php.ini` file is by saving `phpinfo()` output into local file:

```
php -i >> phpinfo-cli.txt
```

Open saved file & find row `Loaded Configuration File`. It will contain path to actually loaded `php.ini` file e.g.:

```
Loaded Configuration File => D:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini
```

The above assumes that PHP is properly installed, e.g. on Windows included in `PATH` env. variable.

Comment: How does that answer the question? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57755449/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry, I thought it was obvious. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux it is usually under `/usr/bin/php`

To find php.ini loaded in CLI on widows, run:

```
php.exe -i | grep "php.ini"
```

[image]

Ps. You can localize PHP installation folder with:

```
which php
```

[image]

or

```
whereis php
```

> /c/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64/php

Answer (score 1):

In a Docker container, *"[phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/)"*. there isn't any *php.ini* file. But there are two files: *php.ini-debug* and *php.ini-production*.

To solve the problem, simply rename one of the files to *php.ini* and restart the Docker container.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that Docker container/image, *"phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin"*?

Answer (score -6):

There is no *php.ini* used by the command line. You have to copy the file from `...EasyPHP-<<version>>\apache\php.ini` to `...EasyPHP-<<version>>\php\php.ini` and then edit the one in the **php** directory.

Reference:

- *[Why can't CakePHP bake connect to MySQL running under EasyPHP on Windows Vista Ultimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828899/why-cant-cakephp-bake-connect-to-mysql-running-under-easyphp-on-windows-vista-u/1961355#1961355)*

Comment: It would be better to quote the source: *"The root cause of the problem is that in EasyPHP 5.3 there isn't any* ***php.ini*** *file in the* ***php*** *folder."*