# where can I find the php.ini for php-cli

Tags: php, php-ini

It appears that the php command line is using a different php.ini from the main php interpreter. I am using Ubuntu 10.4. My problem is that in the main php.ini I have included an extra path for an external library, but in the cli version this is not present, and so I have a path inclusion error.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the php.ini file used by the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Just ask PHP:

```
php -i |grep php\.ini
```

Comment: Better answer than mine, as it'll work for non-default and non-Ubuntu uses.

Comment: I get `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib64`, but the php.ini is not in this folder.

Comment: If you don't see `php.ini` it means it doesn't exist and PHP takes default values. You can create new `php.ini` file into this directory.

Comment: before creating a new one, check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057175/5011027) as there could be another file somewhere else

Answer (score 72):

Better yet:
`$ php --ini`

This will also show all extra *.ini files loaded (usually hanging around in some conf.d dir in debian):

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
>   Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
>   Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
>   Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/geoip.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imagick.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ldap.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcache.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcached.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/snmp.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite3.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/tidy.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini,
>   /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xsl.ini

Note that this was about php-cli, php-cgi does not have this afaik.

Comment: A note about all the `conf.d` files - in Ubuntu, that folder is a symlink, so they're shared across all PHP uses.

Comment: As it is per default in Debian, assuming one installed from the normal repositories.

Answer (score 8):

At my last job, I got in the habit of specifying my ini file on every execution...

```
C:\php\cli\php.exe -c C:\php\php.ini myscript.php
```

Comment: Interesting. I like it. I just used this now for one of my cron jobs with a custom php.ini file.

Answer (score 3):

You can find php.ini using the below command. in LINUX

```
find / -name php.ini
```

or

```
locate php.ini
```

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: @ninja, why not?

Comment: it simply searches for files which are named like that. it is possible to have several or none of >>php.ini<< files in the system

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting in windows is that in both tests (on apache with phpinfo() and in cli with php --ini), the configuration file path is c:\windows. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/de/configuration.file.php)

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem. Simply check owner and permissions from every files in /etc/php5/conf.d/. It has to be owned by root and readeable by anymone.

Comment: No, it only has to be readable by the process, the owner can be anyone. at least under linux.