# Why PHP error is shown in terminal not shown in browser in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I wrote and executed `PHP` code in the Terminal of Ubuntu.
In this case I got some errors. When I am using the Terminal it shows the error instantaneously. When the same code is run in a browser it doesn't show any error. Why does this happen, and how do I show the error in my browser?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and `display_errors = 1` in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` or `/etc/php/fpm/php.ini` and restart the web service.

Comment: Hi Foozy When I can't change the display = 1 because it shows in Read Only Formate. Now What Can do.

Answer (score 3):

**command line php**  and regular, **web php** (such as apache's) have **different php.ini** files with **different configurations**

What you should do is to **compare the two ini files and find what you need to correct**.

Find `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives.

Comment: not sure why this valid answer is cowardly, quietly downvoted.

Comment: Too generic, doesn't answer the question and looks like something that should have been a comment.

Comment: What is too generic for you? It clearly states there can be different ini this different configured PHPs

Comment: The updated answer is more specific and addresses the problem in the question.