# PHP script for sending mail won't work when executed via browser but work fine when executed from command line

Tags: php, linux, email, xampp, privileges

I've written a little PHP script:

```
<?php
$phpPath = shell_exec("which php");

print "$phpPath\n";
 
$uid =  posix_getuid();
$userinfo = posix_getpwuid($uid);
print_r($userinfo );
print "\n";

    $to = "my_user_name@my_company_mail.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "do-not-reply@akamai.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    $res = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    print_r(error_get_last());
    if($res){
    echo "Mail Sent.\n";
    }else{
    echo "Mail was'nt Sent\n";

    }
?>
```

The thing that drives me crazy is that when I execute this script from command line it work fine:

```
/usr/bin/php

Array
(
    [name] => daemon
    [passwd] => x
    [uid] => 1
    [gid] => 1
    [gecos] => daemon
    [dir] => /usr/sbin
    [shell] => /bin/sh
)

Mail Sent.
```

but when I execute it from a remote browser this what I get:

```
/usr/bin/php

Array
(
    [name] => daemon
    [passwd] => x
    [uid] => 1
    [gid] => 1
    [gecos] => daemon
    [dir] => /usr/sbin
    [shell] => /bin/sh
)

Mail was'nt Sent
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Command Line PHP and PHP doesn't use the same php.ini, please check if you have difference between them.

[More information on php.ini here](http://php.net/manual/fr/configuration.file.php)

[Related question on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli/3057175#3057175)

Comment: I've copied the the cli php.ini to lampp directory, nothing changed, all the mail configuration were the same anyway...