# Unable to install my symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, mamp

I'm using MAMP for Windows 10 , and  I have a problem when I try to make a project with symfony. I install symfony with the installer and when I launch the command "php symfony new my_project_name", the installation doesn't work because of a time zone error.

To find the php.ini, I launch the php info on MAMP and it displays this
"Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\WINDOWS

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.3\php.ini "
```

and I checked on apache con (C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf) for PHPIniDir  :  PHPIniDir "C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.3\php.ini"

I modify the timezone parameter as follows

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

and I launch the check but it seems that I didn't modify the right file. Also, there is a problem with my php.in; the following errors occur

```
Symfony2 Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  WARNING: No configuration file (php.ini) used by PHP!

> Checking Symfony requirements:
  .....E................W...WW.W.....

 [ERROR]
 Your system is not ready to run Symfony2 projects

Fix the following mandatory requirements
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * date.timezone setting must be set
   > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).
```

Comment: Using a mac, I had to remove the semi-colin but I see you already did that.
 ```Additionally I had to sudo cp etc/php.ini.default etc/php.ini```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the PHP CLI uses a different php.ini configuration than the Apache PHP. Could you check where is the right configuration file for command line? [This topic can help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli)

Then when you'll find it, just do the same as you did with the MAMP php.ini. It should work.

Comment: Hello, i check by using php.ini and it seems php cli

Comment: Hello, I check by using php -ini and i have "Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS and Loaded Configuration File => (none)" for my php cli. I don't know how to change these values because i can find where they set. I read the page of configuration files in php.net, but as far as i know, i didn't use sapi, i check if i have any environment variable with php but no. And no registry keys also. And i don't want move my php.ini in C:\WINDOWS but i can find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Find PHP.INI file for CLI like this:
hp -i |grep php.ini
and then modify date.timezone in it. Voila! It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for my late answer

Comment: Was it useful? :)