# Using SQLSRV extension in PHP CLI script

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

folks!

This is my first experience with big scripts in PHP CLI and I'm facing a 'not found' error when using the `sqlsrv_connect` function in my script.
Running the script in the browser is okay, connects all fine, the queries goes as fine as it could; but when in the CLI, my friend, it shows

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

What could it be, dark magic or newbie developer?

This is how i use the function:

```
$_dbip = '127.0.0.1';
$_dbnome = $nome_bd;
$_dbuid = 'sa';
$_dbpwd = 'very_strong_secret_pwd';

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($_dbip, array('Database' => $_dbnome, 'UID' => $_dbuid, 'PWD' => $_dbpwd)) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your PHP code? May help others determine what the issue is.

Comment: Just edited the question, adding the code. It's very simple, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that the PDO version of SQLSRV was the one activated. I really just got a single `php.ini` file and simply added a new line declaring the SQLSRV without the PDO.

Thanks for the help, still!

Answer (score 1):

There are two `php.ini` files , one for the `CLI` and one for the Web browser.

You need to make sure the extension is enable on both.

You should use `PDO` if possible, because it is a better extension and it supports `SQL server`.

Comment: Really? I just got one `php.ini` in my installation, is that right? If not, where I should probably find the CLI `php.ini`

Comment: @IvanCézanne you running PHP on linux or windows

Comment: Nope, ain't working out. Just got a single `php.ini` and it got the extensions activated correctly.

Comment: @IvanCézanne Im pretty sure you have 2, but you can force it  like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3057474/1880431