# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13) Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, ubuntu

I have checked status of mysql by `sudo service mysql status` and get the following output:

```
 mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-07-22 15:06:35 IST; 11s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4946 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS

Jul 22 15:06:35 ubuntu-lenovo systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql
Jul 22 15:06:35 ubuntu-lenovo systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql
```

But when I try it to run via terminal it says:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

When I try to run with host i.e. `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -uroot` it says:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

I have tried almost every solution from SO.

Comment: Try restarting MySQL and Apache services

Comment: Show your **mysql.sock** page?

Comment: where is mysql.sock file?

Comment: I gave my answer. Go through it step by step.

Comment: didn't work even after purging, reinstalling mysql

Comment: worked now after manually starting mysql

Answer (score 1):

Simply check your **my.cnf** *(mysql configuration file)* and change from

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

to

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

if you don't have that parameter just add it.

Binding to the 0.0.0.0 let your mysql being available on every IP configured cause you can't bind just on two or three IP on the server, the config can be: localhost or everything.

Then check your /etc/hosts file and be sure that the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Next, restart your mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your **php.ini** file in your system using `$ php -i |grep php\.ini` command OR Find Using this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli)
2. Open **php.ini** file.
3. And, make sure these lines are present or not.

   a) `extension=mysql.so`  b)`extension=pdo_mysql.so`
4. If Yes, remove (;) this before them.
5. If not present, run this command `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Now, type `php artisan migrate` command. I'm sure you will get **error**

> can't connect to local MYSQL server through socket

Now,

- Change bind-address from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`
- Run `/opt/lampp/bin/php`.
- After running this if you get

> "unable to load dynamic library"

Then, remove `php_mssql.dll extension` (for non-windows)

- If not getting error, come directly to **Project-Name-Folder/config/database.php** file and add this code `'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'`,

Find the complete path of `mysql.sock`, and add it

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'danishLara'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock', //Add this line here
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Comment: Could not open input file: artisan on running php artisan migrate

Comment: @عثمانغني: Open `'/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',` and add `'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',`

Comment: No data present there in **mysql.sock** ?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen after the homebrew installation and sometimes occurs due to permission issues. The following commands fixed the same problem on my computer.

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql

sudo mysql.server start
```