# PHP70 PDO Error + Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO'

Tags: php, pdo

I know this error message has been described before and I've tried the fixes like adding pdo.so to php.ini etc.

The main difference I have is PDO works fine for the websites on the server I'm running - it just fails for commandline scripts I use to update the database. So essentially it works but not in all situations.

This was working before I upgraded to PHP7.0.8/9

```
sudo yum list installed php70*
Loaded plugins: priorities, replace, update-motd, upgrade-helper
958 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
php70.x86_64                 7.0.8-1.13.amzn1                      @amzn-updates
php70-cli.x86_64             7.0.8-1.13.amzn1                      @amzn-updates
php70-common.x86_64          7.0.8-1.13.amzn1                      @amzn-updates
php70-json.x86_64            7.0.8-1.13.amzn1                      @amzn-updates
php70-php-bcmath.x86_64      7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-cli.x86_64         7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-common.x86_64      7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-fpm.x86_64         7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-gd.x86_64          7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-json.x86_64        7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-mbstring.x86_64    7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64      7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-mysqlnd.x86_64     7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-opcache.x86_64     7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-pdo.x86_64         7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-pear.noarch        1:1.10.1-4.el6.remi                   @remi-safe
php70-php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64
                             1.2.2-0.2.20160715gita87a993.el6.remi @remi-safe
php70-php-pecl-redis.x86_64  3.0.0-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-process.x86_64     7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-php-xml.x86_64         7.0.9-1.el6.remi                      @remi-safe
php70-process.x86_64         7.0.8-1.13.amzn1                      @amzn-updates
php70-runtime.x86_64         1.0-5.el6.remi                        @remi-safe
php70-xml.x86_64             7.0.8-1.13.amzn1                      @amzn-updates
```

Is there a way to manually include PDO Class?

Any reason why this would fail only on commandline?
Note: I'm using the same database.class.php (that I've written) for both web and commandline - same class but different results.

thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a Red Hat or Centos? tbh it could be other flavors as well but i would guess your path in bash points to the wrong php executable. Honestly it's hard to say though

Comment: yes Centos - ok I'll have a look at the path... thankyou

Comment: Maybe its the mix of PHP .8 and .9 - the installs are coming form 2 different locations - remi and amzn

Comment: It sounds like you have a `namespace` statement somewhere in your script, so in that case you'd need to instantiate the PDO object with a backslash for the root namespace `$pdo = new \PDO`

Comment: I tried the \PDO but same outcome - thanks for the idea :)

Comment: You likely have two different `php.ini` config files; one for web and another for CLI. Run `php -i` in your console and see what configuration files are loaded. The CLI one probably doesn't have the PDO and pdo_mysql extensions loaded. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli

Comment: yes php -i does not have any reference to pdo - thanks I'll try the stack link - appreciated

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?  You can use <?php phpinfo(); ?> to check if PDO has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different PHP stacks installed.

- php70-* (7.0.8 from amzn), those are probably "base" packages, and probably provide /usr/bin/php, but don't have the PDO extension (php-pdo package)
- php70-php-* (7.0.9 from remi), which is a Software Collection, design for parallel installation, which provide the php70 command (you can also use "scl enable php70 php" command)

More information about SCL in [Remi's FAQ](http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

Comment: You were exactly right and it's so obvious now. I've removed the AWS php packages and reinstall php via remi. All is on the same version now and everything is working. greatly grealy greatly appreciate your time... THANKS!!!