# PHP (cli) version doesn't match XAMPP version I installed

Tags: php, xampp, grav

Recently I installed XAMPP for doing local development on my Windows 7 machine.  I honestly didn't think PHP was installed at all before hand.  I installed the latest version of XAMPP and configured for php 5.6.24. I created some virtual hosts and everything seemed to work.

I was having an issue and I needed to confirm which version of PHP I was using so I opened up my command line and typed `php -v`.  For some reason it is reporting I'm using PHP 5.4.25.  The exact line is `PHP 5.4.25 (cli) (built: Feb  5 2014 21:19:58)`

I don't recall using this version (I had Visual Studio Community installed recently, is that related?). I don't understand either why my CLI is reporting one version, when XAMPP supposedly installed another version.  Am I missing something?  I need to run some gpm commands for the latest version of `Grav CMS` but when I do it says it required at least 5.5.9.

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli) and you should be able to see where php is installed

Comment: Looks like there was a PHP already installed in your server. Go to enviromen vars and take a look to PATH content, if there is a php path there then replaced it by your new PHP path (xampp)

Comment: try typing `where php` to see which php exe it is pointing to.  Update your Windows environment path variables to point the XAMPP bin path.

Comment: Ahhh it's pointing to an old xampp portable I had in my dropbox...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple versions of php installed.

You will want to ensure that you are executing the php-cli that came with XAMPP.

It sounds like you have another version of php installed and is in your `PATH` so that when you run `php` that version is loaded.

You can use the `where` command to find out what file is being loaded.
From the terminal type: `where php`

- I am not a windows guy but there is a `which` command on linux. Apparently this is the command for windows. Here is a SO post about it:
  [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Anyways, you may want to remove that php file and possibly create a symbolic link in its place for the XAMPP version of `php-cli`

If you remove/rename the file and the new `php-cli` is not in your path, you will probably get an error as the system will not know what `php` is.

Comment: Thank you!  This was it.  I was able to point to my newer php install and it works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @drpcken can you tell me how ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to **uninstall all the xampp's** that are installed and then fresh install xampp with php version > 7.

Everything should work fine then.

> What happened to me was that I had installed xampp two times. One
>   xampp on my C:// (version 5.6) and one xampp on my D:// (version 7.2)
>
> When I did the command on my D:// xampp
>
> ```
> php --version
> ```
>
> It took the xampp php version from the C:// instead of the D://.