# PHP Core extensions directory in linux are not loaded via PHP cli

Tags: php, linux

I have compiled php myself. With a set of config opetions to have the important extensions.

When I check the php-info with http (browser), I see all extensions are loaded.

But, when I check the `phpinfo` with php on the cli, the extensions are not listed. I even cannot find `.so` files of extensions in any directory. For instance, `dom.so` is not found anywhere (in no possible directory such as `/usr/local/php7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012` )

Php cli points to a directory of extensions .ini files. In there, I do no see many extensions which are loaded via apache.

Update:

I have `./configure` and `make install` dom extension myself from within the raw files in `extensions/dom` dir of php. I then have added manually a `.ini` file to php cli. The php cli loads the extensions, but throws an error the it is not a  valid library.

Comment: Do you have the correct extensions marked in the php.ini used by the cli? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli

Comment: @glaux  What do you mean by correct?

Comment: If the configuration is correct in apache/nginx but not in cli, perhaps they are using two different php.ini files. Try running `php --ini` and see if the php.ini with the extensions enabled are present.

Comment: Read the updated question

Comment: That is out of my league atm, sorry.