# Undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu

OS  Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7.0

All drivers install used this manual ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac )

updated php.ini

[image]

But still, have this error.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Konstantin

Comment: Do you get that error through the web server or when you run a script through cli?

Comment: This error from Visual Studio Code debugger.  From web server.  Error information: 
SQLSTATE: HYT00
Code: 0
Message: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
SQLSTATE: 08001
Code: 87
Message: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
SQLSTATE: 08001  But all connection information correct. I can connect to this database using  SSMS with out any problem.

Comment: What does that error have to do with your question?? Getting a connection error is not the same as "Undefined function".

Comment: When I run code from  VSC I have this error  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in.... When I run the same code from WEB  error Connection string is not valid. The same code generates two different type of error. So to whom believe?

Comment: My guess would be that VSC runs PHP through command line (to check for errors etc.) so you need to enable the extension for cli as well. It's the same way as for Apache2, but that ini file is usually located in: `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`.

Comment: it's already enabled  extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so

Comment: Thank you, Magnus Eriksson. I don't have any idea why,  but after restart Ubuntu, connection to the SQL  server from the web is established.  But VSC still generate the same error  Undefined function sqlsrv_connect().  
Konstantin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where can I find the php.ini for php-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057110/1255289)