# Call to undefined function curl_init() on console Command laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to call `curl_init()` on console Command `laravel` but I'm getting error "Call to undefined function `curl_init()`" ?

but when I call `curl_init()` from Controller `laravel` is working fine.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [where can I find the php.ini for php-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using two different PHP installations in command line and on your local web server.

To verify that, check both versions: run `php -v` in command line to see what version is running in command line, and load a web page on your browser with this content for your webserver PHP version: `<?php phpinfo();`

If that is the case, activate "php_curl" extension on your command line installation.

Answer (score -1):

This error appears when curl extension is not being installed or activated.
Run php -m command in your terminal or cmd to check whether curl is listed or not.