Shopware 6.6.6.1 new setup having bin/console problem
I've setup shopware 6 latest version 6.6.6.1. on my server as staging for migration from shopware 5 to shopware 6. And while migration process of customer and orders I choose to migrate those data via cli because the data of the customer and order is more then >200000.
And I tried to start the migration and hit the command,
php bin/console migration:start customersOrders

it outputs error like which is coming from console i.e.,
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /home/someDirectory/hostFolder/hostFolder-stage/bin/console on line 47

console file code,
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Kernel\KernelFactory;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\KernelPluginLoader\DbalKernelPluginLoader;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\KernelPluginLoader\StaticKernelPluginLoader;
use Shopware\Core\Kernel;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$envFile = __DIR__ . '/../.env';

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../.env') && !file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../.env.dist') && 
!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../.env.local.php')) {
    $_SERVER['APP_RUNTIME_OPTIONS']['disable_dotenv'] = true;
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return static function (array &$context) {
    set_time_limit(0);

    $classLoader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    if (!class_exists(Application::class)) {
        throw new RuntimeException('You need to add "symfony/framework-bundle" as a Composer 
dependency.');
    }

if (!isset($context['PROJECT_ROOT'])) {
    $context['PROJECT_ROOT'] = dirname(__DIR__);
}

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], $context['APP_ENV'] ?? 'prod', true);
$debug = ($context['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ($env !== 'prod')) && !$input->hasParameterOption('--no-debug', true);

$pluginLoader = new StaticKernelPluginLoader($classLoader, null);

if ($input->getFirstArgument() === 'system:install') {
    $context['INSTALL'] = true;
}

if (trim($context['DATABASE_URL'] ?? '') !== '' && !isset($context['INSTALL'])) {
    $pluginLoader = new DbalKernelPluginLoader($classLoader, null, Kernel::getConnection());
}

$kernel = KernelFactory::create(
    environment: $env,
    debug: $debug,
    classLoader: $classLoader,
    pluginLoader: $pluginLoader
);

$application = new Application($kernel);
$kernel->boot();

$application->setName('Shopware');
$application->setVersion($kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.shopware_version'));

return $application;

};
php version: 8.3

Do you want any other details please let me know in the comments section.

Which PHP version are you using? "System requirements : tested on PHP 8.2 and 8.3" - documentation

I'm using PHP 8.3 version.

I would recommend to post an issue on the Shopware's github - Before this, please verify that the CLI's PHP version is in fact PHP8.2+ (It could be that PHP's CLI you use, is using another php.ini - You can verify this by running php -v)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli

@Soteris92: Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.
