# can't seem to access php.ini

Tags: php, shell

I'm using shell to login to an ubuntu server.  I want to enable curl in php.ini

I used the command whereis php.ini which shows /usr/bin/php as the location for php.ini.

However everytime I try to CD into php it says 'php is not a directory'  How can I edit my php.ini?

Or do I need to create one somewhere else?

Comment: Buttloads of misunderstandings there. You can't use `whereis php.ini` as it only works with the executable. And the executable and the ini file are two distinct things. Then you can't `cd` to files. How did you come to that idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the php.ini file used by the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line)

Comment: @mario I didn't think cd would work but I tried in vain, I'm still a linux newbie.  I did misunderstand the use of whereis, thankfully I have gotten a whole bunch of help from everyone here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/usr/bin/php is the executable interpreter for PHP.

You need to locate your existing php.ini file:

```
$ find / -name php.ini
```

You would expect to find it somewhere in /etc, so you might find this is quicker:

```
$ find /etc -name php.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP will tell you where it loaded the configuration file from or where it expects it by running:

```
php --ini
```

Or:

```
php -i | grep -i php.ini
```