# Symfonys date_default_timezone_get()

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime

So I installed composer and apache and mysql, and then installed symfony, but after the installation it tells me to change the date because it is not reliable and then I can use it freely.

I have changed the date in php.ini with Europe/Bucharest but is still get this message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system'  
s timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or  
the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those me  
thods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th  
e timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please s  
et date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

I use fedora 23 32-bit.I have looked over other solutions but none of them work.

Comment: Did you restarted Apache? Please add in your question the configuration you added in `php.ini`.

Comment: Restart your server and have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595942/mamp-symfony-mamp-overrides-date-timezone-setting-from-php-ini-symfony-fails

Comment: I have restarted the Apache server, did change the php.ini with vi like ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595942/mamp-symfony-mamp-overrides-date-timezone-setting-from-php-ini-symfony-fails )
and nothing changed, the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Symfony2 just add this at the end of your class app/AppKernel.php :

```
public function init() {
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Bucharest' );
    parent::init();
}
```

In Symfony3, use :

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

Comment: I added it, it took him a moment and told me the same thing, should i reinstall or something? new to symfony.

Comment: It always worked fine for me, are you sure you picked the right version and added between the braces of the class AppKernel ?

Comment: Yes i did try both of them. i will check again to see if it is between the braces.

Comment: got this now, after i verified and modified a bit 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /home/m80/my_project/app/AppKernel.php on line 28

Comment: I think you forgot to close a brace somewhere in your file, or something like that

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
This is the error that gives now, from one thing to another. Sorry for being such a newbie.

Comment: Try to verify everything in your file, like quotes, end of lines, etc. And maybe delete your folders in your cache directory, …

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
{
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai');
}
```

I use this in symphony 2.3