# command line php,socket

Tags: php, websocket

I tried to run in my localhost (WAMP) a php code with a socket,and it work great in the browser ,but whan i tried to do the same in the command line it's throw exception "the function socket_create is not exists" .
So I tried to check if php_sockets extintion is enabled and it is,so it still doesn't work ,someone has crossed with that before ?
here is the exception :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function socket_create() in
>   C:\wamp\www\sock et\serverc.php on line 2 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1.
>   {main}() C:\wamp\www\socket\serverc.php:0
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in
>   C:\wamp\www\socket\se rverc.php on line 2
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0010     230696   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\socket\serverc.php:0

Comment: Maybe there is a different php.ini for cli (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line)

Comment: maybe ,but you know where in wamp this folder located ?

Comment: execute this line `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`

Comment: sorry i didnt notice ...
php -i | find /i "Configuration File"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini
i eduted the second one (i think ) .. and i didnt found the first one...

Comment: never mind Probably windoes re edit this file or somthing

Answer (score 0):

PHP in CLI mode on Windows uses the `php.ini` file located in `C:\Windows` (see http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php). So check here if `php_socket` is enabled.