# How to change PHP master value of memory_limit

Tags: php

I trying to change the php memory_limit **master value** but still cant make it.

in htaccess i put '**php_value memory_limit 1024M**', it's only change the **local value**..

Any ideas to change the master value?

Answer (score 1):

Update your php.ini file. If you are on shared hosting without access to it, then your only option is to set it locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the master value, you'll need to find the php.ini file located on the server. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2750582/254973 if you need help finding the file.

Simply edit the value within that php.ini file, and you should be good to go. Maybe a restart of the webserver depending on it's configuration.

This will more than likely require elevated/root access on your hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of your php.ini file

php -i | grep php.ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/lib/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/lib/php.ini

Something like this and edit the file with your favorite editor:
notepad, vim, emacs, pico...

pico /usr/lib/php.ini

Search and change memory limit and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Change the php ini
memory_limit = 128M
to what you want

Answer (score 0):

I was searching all over the system for this value, it seems it's stored in

```
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

I tried to change the memory_limit in these files but didn't change anything:

```
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
```

Don't forget to restart the php and webserver (nginx/apache etc.) service after editing.