# The command php --ini never returns a result

Tags: php, command-line

I was trying to find the location of my php.ini file, and an answer to [How to find the php.ini file used by the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line) stated I could find that information within the result returned by `php --ini`.  But when I tried this, the command never returns a result (I've tried several times, with 10+ minute waits).  No errors are given; it seems to be stuck in a loop.  Other PHP commands, such as `php -i` do work.  What causes this? And can I do something to fix it?

Comment: Try `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` **(unix)**, `php -i | find /i "Configuration File"` **(windows)**

Comment: if `php -i` works, you can  find out ini location with `php -i | grep ini`

Comment: I've never seen anybody use `--ini`, nor is it [in the list of options](http://www.php-cli.com/php-cli-options.shtml)

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali.  I had just realized that I missed that solution among the other answers.  I'm still curious why `php --ini` is not working, if you have any insights.

Comment: @Elias - it does exist (and works) with all versions of PHP I have installed (5.2-5.5), and is documented http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: @ctogden: `php --ini` works perfectly fine on my Unix system. Output: http://pastie.org/8100663

Answer (score 0):

I checked my version number. I don't have the required version for `--ini`.

I'm running PHP 5.1.2.  According to the PHP Manual Page shared by @MarkBaker the `--ini` option is "Available as of PHP 5.2.3."