# PHP command in Ubuntu returning text of PHP file

Tags: php, ubuntu, shorttags

I've been trying to run my PHP scripts on my Ubuntu 13.10 machine, but unusually it returns the PHP file contents.

```
php -q discover/server.php
<?

// configuration settings
require "config.php";

function pollCallback()
{
        $poller = new Poller_Discover ();
        $poller->check ();
}

$daemon = new Core_Daemon ( 'pollCallback', true );
```

I find this very unusual because I have already turned PHP's `enable_short_tag` configuration on.

Comment: How did you turn on short tags?

Comment: I've changed the php.ini file and modified

Comment: It "usually" returns the php contents? You mean it does it when you use the short tag syntax?

Comment: Which php.ini file? Are you sure it's the same one that PHP is actually reading?

Comment: People work SO HARD to avoid typing three characters.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll try using the one without the short tags. wait for a while :)

Comment: Are you sure you changed the correct php.ini file? There are usually multiple of those and one is used for CLI.

Comment: Alkar! thank you very much! :)

I didn't know that there is a separate ini file for the php-cli.

Thank you! :)

Comment: @NielRiddle no worries, I'll add an answer :)

Comment: This question was resolved by this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try enabling short tags in the appropriate `php.ini` file which is being used by the CLI php command. Its location might be distribution-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a console script like that you have 2 options, you mixed them thus it doesnt work:

Use of a SHEBANG:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
/*
code
*/
```

ran by `./discover/server.php` (make sure it's executable with chmod 700 / 770 / 777).

---

Or sending the script to php:

```
<?php
/*
code
*/
```

ran by `php -q discover/server.php`.

You should also not use short tags `<? /* */ ?>` as they are `off` by default on most servers.

Also check you have the correct php.ini file, there are different versions for apache, fpm, cli (<- is what you need), cgi, ...