# Php artisan migrate command

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate

I tried to run `php artisan migrate` but I'm getting an error:

> In Connection.php line 664: could not find driver (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and
>   table_name = migration) In Connector.php line 67: could not find
>   driver.

Comment: Would you please share with us your **_.env_** file configurations so we can check whether it has anything to do with it?(Which is possibly the reason of why you are getting this error)

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=okeada DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=null. That's database credentials on my .env file

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.2.0

Comment: Are you sure that there is no conflict between the PHP that is used by Apache and the PHP that is linked to the command line?

Comment: How do I know or detect if there's conflict. And there's any conflict, how do I solve the issue. Kindly assist I'm new in coding

Comment: I will redirect to you to a similar issue. Please check the following [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc)

Comment: which php doesn't run. It gives me: "which" is not defined.

Comment: I tried to edit the php.ini on c://php/PHP.ini to look like c://wamp64/bin/php7/php.ini but I'm getting another error relating mbstring & openssl module

Comment: Thanks for your responses but then I've not gotten any solution to the problem. As I said earlier, I'm very very new in coding plz assist me to do this right - I believe it's possible. Thanks & God bless

Comment: Plz note that I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

you should run this command , that's because cache

```
composer dumpautoload
```