# Could not find driver while migrating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I wanna make a migration by **php artisan migrate** but I get an error:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 67:
  could not find driver
```

My env file settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: try clearing cache, fire command `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Is PDO installed? Check your PHP CLI configuration.

Comment: Yeah, PDO is defenetly installed, I've used it many times without laravel

Comment: Make sure it's installed for CLI as well. Do `php -i | grep -i pdo`. Configurations can differ between command line and browser.

Comment: can you try to change port as 33060 ?

Comment: if you have custom codes in `appserviceprovider` remove them, migrate and again put them back.

Comment: look at this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install php-mysql driver.