# could not find driver in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lamp, manjaro

i receive this error when sending a request from angular project .

> could not find driver (SQL: insert into `employees` (`name`, `address`, `gender`, `department_id`, `education`, `experiance`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Karly Frost, Aliquam quo anim illum et nisi occaecat quam ad ut eveniet animi natus, f, 2, Eveniet in ab architecto neque ut molestiae magnam aliquip deleniti dolores quia hic est nobis tempora rerum, Laboriosam reprehenderit sint minima dolore quis dolorem perferendis, 2018-05-20 22:54:20, 2018-05-20 22:54:20))

but when i try to add new record using

> php artisan tinker command and execute insert query using laravel eloquent it works very well

else i got this exception

> notice : i use arch manjaro as my linux distributions

Comment: Do you have fillable in your model?

Comment: Yes I do here it is 
protected $fillable = ['name','address','gender','department_id','education','experiance','birthdate'];

Comment: Have you checked env file? Are database settings correct?

Comment: every thing is correct if not it i wan't be able to insert in tinker

Comment: Then this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql

Comment: Or this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/could-not-find-driver-error-in-laravel-55

Comment: it is not related to the issue configurations are good

Comment: Well then someone else might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install PDO on your server. Edit your php.ini (look at your phpinfo(), "Loaded Configuration File" line, to find the php.ini file path). Find and uncomment the following line (remove the ; character):

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then, restart your Apache server. For more information, please  read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there's a conflict between the PHP that is used by Apache and the PHP that is linked to the command line. check your PHP version and settings , i hope that this can help

thanks to [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc)

and check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104320/6305353)