# PHP 7.2 memcached extension on Mac OS

Tags: php, symfony, memcached, macos-sierra

I am trying to setup php memcached extension on mac OS High Sierra. I am running php 7.2

Output of php -v:

```
PHP 7.2.6 (cli) (built: May 25 2018 06:18:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I installed [memcached](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) via `pecl` without any error:

```
pecl install memcached
```

It is enabled in php.ini file:

```
extension="memcached.so"
```

When I run `<?php echo phpinfo();?>` on my Apache server. I can see session configured:

```
session.save_handler    memcached   memcached
```

My symfony application gives me still this error:

```
(1/1) ClassNotFoundException
Attempted to load class "Memcached" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

EDIT:

My apache is running a different version of php (PHP Version 7.1.16) I don't know why but I think this cannot be a problem.

In info file I can see in the **CORE section** that php extension dir is `"/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718"`. When I open that directory there is `memcached.so` file. The path is correct.

EDIT 2:

In my apache logs I see warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718/memcached.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718/memcached.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_empty_string\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718/memcached.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718/memcached.so in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: "on my Apache server. I can see memcached enabled" is wrong. What you see is that you set session save handler to memcached. You should see a separate memcached block in phpinfo output, i.e. a separate table with those purple and grey colours. Check which ini file Aapache mod is using, it's also in there.

Comment: In that case I don't see it but I can see memcached extension when I run this command  `php -m | grep memcached`

Comment: Have you verified that the ini file phpinfo is telling is in use is the one you are editing? Are you sure php -m lists 'memcached' and not 'memcache'?

Comment: Yes I have. My apache is using different `php.ini` file in `/etc/php.ini` but it is enabled there as well and yes it is memcached not memcache.

Comment: Surely, PHP isn't loading those ini files in which the module is enabled since then you would see the memcached block in phpinfo output. It is quite clear from the values in 'Loaded Configuration File' and 'Additional .ini files parsed' which files are loaded.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am 100% sure that I am editing right `php.ini`. `Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini`. Maybe there can be a problem with php version. My php -v shows 7.2.6 but apache shows 7.1.16? is it possible to change it?

Comment: For using memcache with PHP we also need php-memcached

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc/42925908#42925908 . You seem to be using a different PHP configuration on CLI and Apache. You need to make sure you're using the same ones

Answer (score 1):

So. Apache and SLI php version use diferent php.ini files.
For examle on my Debian 9 it use /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

I believe your problem is that you are using a different version of PHP.

Just try comands below:

```
$sudo a2dismod php7.1
$sudo a2enmod php7.2
$sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you still get same Error try create info.php in your www root dir thich conteint next code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

And check Memcache are loaded.

Comment: Thanks but these commands doesn't exist on MacOS. I am getting `sudo: a2dismod: command not found`

Comment: So, ok! Can you create info.php which conteint "<?php phpinfo();" around your index.php. Go to http://127.0.0.1/info.php and find "Configuraton File (php.ini) Path" line.

Comment: Did you used brew to install apache & php?

Comment: I already did it. My php.ini is located in `/etc/php.ini`. In that file I added `extension="memcached.so"` and restarted Apache. But it didn't work. When I run Symfony built-in server (on the php7.2) everything works fine and memcached is loaded.

Comment: Apache was preinstalled. And I upgraded php via brew.

Comment: Which php apache modules availible in your /etc/httpd/httpd.conf? It showld be something like 'LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your cli and apache use different php.ini files. If your apache use `/etc/php.ini` and you added extension line it mean you have't memcache.so in your php7.1 version extension_dir.

Comment: `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` Yes, you are right and I mentioned it in my description of problem. My extension_dir is correct for apache configuration - `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718`.  I edited my question with log from apache.

Comment: What returns `pecl version` ?

Comment: `PEAR Version: 1.10.5
PHP Version: 7.2.6
Zend Engine Version: 3.2.0` - but this is from my CLI.

Comment: Let's try reconfig your cli PHP version. What returns `ls -Al /usr/bin | grep php`?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  11157808 30 May 00:36 php`

Comment: Bad case. =) Let's try `php --ini`.

Comment: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini`

Comment: Ok! As you can see your php7.2 placed in /usr/local/. Let's try `grep -r "libphp7.so" /usr/local` or `grep -r "apache2/libphp" /usr/local`

Comment: What am I looking for? There were more grep matches.

Comment: We are looking for a libphp7.so file for which allow us configure apache2 with php7.2 version. it should be some thing like this - `#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`. Also we can try reinstall apache2 via brew. (https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions)