# Database Error : Can not migratet to Database (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have configured all I need to use the Laravel Framework, and when I was trying to migrate all the scripts to database (migrating), I got myself on trouble. I got this massage :

> Exception trace:   1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
>
> 2
>   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel",
>   "root", "", [])
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

Please somebody help to get out from this !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Error \[PDOException\]: Could not Find Driver in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 on PHP 7.0: PDO Exception - Could not find driver (MySQL)c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your php 
Please try this 
sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common
sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli

[see this article for more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04/1000027#1000027?newreg=d95a452874554f01919cbf6e86a05583)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but I solved in this way 
(if you use xampp on windows you can do the following)

1. Find php.ini file mostly it is included with php when you download it (for me I found in c:/php/ 'beacuse i downloaded the php at that location ')
   "you can also use xampp to find it "
2. Open it with notepad as administrator
3. Search for (;extension=pdo_mysql)  and (;extension=pdo_pgsql)
4. Remove the (;) and then save it now try to run the migration again.
5. If it not work try to see what type of extension is required and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but I wanted to run SQLite instead of MySQL. I simply removed `;` from `extension=pdo_sqlite` in `php.ini`. Then it worked.