# How to resolve Laravel - COULD NOT FIND DRIVER error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, driver

I am using XAMPP on Ubuntu 18.0.4. I am using PHP 7.2.

The Laravel Home page gets loaded at localhost:8000, but when I try to register a user. It shows the following error

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeZWx.png)

I've tried all the things suggested on the internet like changing the php.ini file and all, but I couldn't get a work around.

This is my configuration
Ubuntu 18.04
PHP 7.2

cofig/database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

I've already installed php-mysql using `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

But nothing seems to work
My php.ini file is at /opt/lampp/etc/ and I've following so called solution content

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I've tried to clear the cache too, but nothing works.

> NOTE: THIS SAME EXACT PROJECT WAS WORKING A FEW DAYS AGO. BUT IT SEEMS
>   TO HAVE THIS PROBLEM SINCE TWO DAYS BACK.

Comment: Go to the command line and run `which mysql` and add the output to your question.

Comment: What is in `config/database.php`?

Comment: You try to use `mysql`, but loading `pdo` driver

Comment: @TarekAdam Hello, thanks for your valuable time sir. which mysql command shows no output.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysqlc

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, restarting my computer did the trick and it all started working again.