# could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@gmail.com limit 1)"

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

please help me i am a noober in laravel and i got this error when i try to select something from the database i get this error even when i try to login using the default login for laravel (auth) i also get this error  so please help because i am working on a project and i don't if there is some missing settings or other thing because i have like two project with laravel but i never got this problem before

```html
Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message "could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@gmail.com limit 1)"

Stacktrace:
#79 Illuminate\Database\QueryException in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
#78 PDOException in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
#77 PDO:__construct in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
#76 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector:createPdoConnection in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:46
#75 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector:createConnection in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php:24
#74 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector:connect in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:182
#73 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory:Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:916
#72 call_user_func in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:916
#71 Illuminate\Database\Connection:getPdo in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:941
#70 Illuminate\Database\Connection:getReadPdo in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:399
#69 Illuminate\Database\Connection:getPdoForSelect in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:325
#68 Illuminate\Database\Connection:Illuminate\Database\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657
#67 Illuminate\Database\Connection:runQueryCallback in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
#66 Illuminate\Database\Connection:run in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:333
#65 Illuminate\Database\Connection:select in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2027
#64 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:runSelect in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2015
#63 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:Illuminate\Database\Query\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2499
#62 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:onceWithColumns in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2016
#61 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:get in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:516
#60 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder:getModels in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:500
#59 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder:get in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php:77
#58 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder:first in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:128
#57 Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider:retrieveByCredentials in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php:351
#56 Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard:attempt in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php:79
#55 App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:attemptLogin in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php:44
#54 App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:login in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#53 call_user_func_array in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#52 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45
#51 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:212
#50 Illuminate\Routing\Route:runController in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:169
#49 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:679
#48 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#47 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:24
#46 App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#45 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#44 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
#43 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#42 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#41 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:75
#40 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#39 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#38 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#37 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#36 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#35 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:63
#34 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#33 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#32 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#31 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#30 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#29 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66
#28 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#27 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#26 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
#25 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:681
#24 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:656
#23 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:622
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:611
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
#20 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#19 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57
#18 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#17 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#16 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
#15 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#14 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#13 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
#12 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#11 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#10 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
#9 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#8 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#5 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#4 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
#3 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
#2 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/public/index.php:55
#0 require_once in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Hotel/server.php:21
```

Comment: maybe you don't have a database? or your database isn't running

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i am using  **mysql** database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run the migrations?

```php
php artisan migrate
```

Did you config the database in your .env file? [Read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database)

Comment: i tried but migration is also not working the are still telling pdo     **could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = hotel and table_name = migrations)**

Comment: It seems that you need to install/activate the php pdo extension. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463614/php-artisan-migrate-throwing-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-using-larav) other answer.

Comment: Update your question will all the steps that you did or didn't do so we know more about the cause of the problem.

Comment: as @kennyHorna mentioned just go to your config file and uncomment pdo MySQL extension