# Laravel 5.8 php artisan migrate throwing error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, artisan-migrate

I am using:

- php 7.2
- laravel 5.8
- ubuntu 19

php artisan migrate throwing this error:

```
**Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laraveldb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')**

1. PDOException::("could not find driver")
  /home/amar/sandbox/l5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

2. PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel", "root", "localhost", [])
  /home/amar/sandbox/l5/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove vendor folder and reinstall it using composer install
2. update/install your php extensions (php-mysql, php-mbstring, php-pdo, php-dom)

Above two steps solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in your `php.ini` file and ensure that you have restart the `server` after you make the changes to the `php.ini` file otherwise changes may not be reflected. You can check many approaches in this link also - [click-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463614/php-artisan-migrate-throwing-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-using-larav)

Comment: Thanks. After adding extension=pdo_mysql.so and restarting my server. I again run migrate command and it gives following warning: "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install php7.2-pdo`

Comment: I have already latest version of pdo. But I run sudo apt-get install php-mysql. After this php artisan migrate command runs successfully with this warning: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Migration table created successfully.

Comment: Hmm, remove `extension=pdo_mysql.so` and restart server then check. I think `sudo apt-get install php7.2-pdo` solved your problem.

Comment: Problem finally solved. No warning/error occur this time. Migration runs successfully.