# PDO drrivers no value in Debian 10

Tags: php, linux, pdo, debian

i using Laravel with connected DB. My PHP version 7.4, but i havent noone drivers PDO[image: screenshoot1]

1. I tried uncomment in php.ini `extension=pdo_mysql`, but its not working for me
2. apt-get install php7.4-mysql, again not working
   How to fix that? Thanks all

Comment: are you using PHP as an apache extension or do you use nginx with php-fpm? in both cases you need to restart services after uncommenting lines in ini files

Comment: @jumper85 Thanks for your answer. I dont not what Laravel using. I just write ```php artisan serve``` in terminal

Comment: ah ok, I'm no laravel expert but I checked their docs, this command uses PHP integrated server. IMO if all packages are installed (php-pdo and php-mysql) and enabled in php.ini, then it should work after restarting artisan serve command. seems like others have similar problems, maybe you find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22463614/4239703

Comment: You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) edit configuration files manually to install packages. [php7.4-mysql](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/php7.4-mysql/filelist) already contains a `/usr/share/php7.4-mysql/mysql/pdo_mysql.ini` file with the appropriate settings. Have you installed PHP originally from the same source or it's already a manual setup?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, I installed php 7.4 manually