# Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using XAMPP with PHP Version 5.6.3 and trying to create project in zend framework and executed the command

`zf create project quickstart`

it is giving the `Fatal error: Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0`

.I tried to add comment  "allow_call_time_pass_reference" in "C:\xampp\php\php.ini"

```
; allow_call_time_pass_reference
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

And

```
; should enabled in development environments only.
; Default Value: On (Suppress warnings)
; Development Value: Off (Issue warnings)
; Production Value: Off (Issue warnings)
; http://php.net/allow-call-time-pass-reference
;allow_call_time_pass_reference=Off
```

But it didnt work.Can any one help me. I am using windows machine

Comment: as shown in the [PHP Changelog](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference), it was removed with PHP 5.4. Try updating Zend.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to restart the server or you are editing the incorrect ini configuration file.

- [How to find the php.ini file used by the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line/3744845#3744845)
- [Reload my.cnf without restarting MySql service](https://serverfault.com/questions/79043/reload-my-cnf-without-restarting-mysql-service)