# How activate SSL and EasyPHP 17 under php7.2 and php7.3

Tags: easyphp

How to activate OpenSSL and Sodium in PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3 for EasyPHP 17 and Windows 10?

- In PHP 7.1 I had to change php.ini and remove `;` at the line
  `extension=php_openssl.dll` in order to activate OpenSSL.
- In PHP 7.2?
- In PHP 7.3?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same for 7.2 (line 928) and 7.3 (line 944).

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem enough in php 7.2 and php 7.3 :-(

Comment: Good news :-)
By updating the version of Apache, it's ok !!!
openssl does not work with Apache 2.4.25 x86 and php 7.2 or 7.3
On the other hand, openssl works by putting the version of Apache 2.4.37 x86 in php 7.2 or 7.3

Comment: As said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744845/884195, you can use "php --ini" and find out where your php.ini is. In my case it's [none]. So I created one right inside the php directory

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the OpenSSL extension the same way as in 7.1. In your `php.ini` add/uncomment the line:

```
extension=php_openssl
```

However, as [@Franck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9582063/franck) mentioned, it will not work straight away for PHP 7.2 and 7.3 as there is an incompatibility with Apache 2.4.25 x86 (the default version in EasyPHP 17).

You need to update your Apache to a newer version to make it work. (I tried with Apache 2.4.39 x86 and it works fine).