# How exactly to get AST extension working?

Tags: php

I want install something which requires PHP AST extension. I followed the procedure [found here at GitHub](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast), but I cannot get it to actually work.

Now when I retry installing (`pecl install ast`) I get

> pecl/ast is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.4
>   install failed

But when I check with `php -m`, ast is not listed there, and the plugin I want use also says

> The php-ast extension must be loaded.... install ast and add extension=ast.so to your php.ini.

That's something which I have already done.

And so I am deadlocked and in need of help.

Comment: Maybe your cli php and apache php environments was different. Did you try create php.ini in your public_html directory and check your php.ini directories. Maybe your apache is using php-fpm. You should check your pool configuration.

Comment: @Aaron Yordanyan, Thanks. Your comment helped me to check further and land on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line, which resolved the issue after I found the correct php.ini (It seems there are many, I don't know why they are there, though)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have different php environment in cli and server.

Check your phpinfo and find php.ini path, then try to install(activate) extension for current environment (maybe you using `php-fpm`)

if you using php-fpm then you should configure your pool.