# Load MacOS php.ini config

Tags: php, macos-mojave

I recently uninstalled/deleted my MAMP in the MacOS Mojave. Before deleting it when I try to run `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` and running `phpinfo()` it's loading the MAMP configuration. Now since I deleted MAMP and remove all entry of MAMP in my ~/.bash_profile I was expecting that it will load the default PHP version in my MACOS. But when I tried to run phpinfo() I get this message for the loaded configuration

[image]

How can I tell php to load the default configuration of my Computer? Also I don't know where the default location of php.ini is located

Comment: maybe try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line

Comment: what is the output of the command `which php` ?

Comment: @jonnyjandles this is what I get /usr/bin/php

Comment: @PinksNotDead if you look at my screenshot above you will see I already did the php --ini command