# PHPSTORM/MAMP I've tried everything Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in ... :9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Tags: php, mysqli, phpstorm, mamp, php-7.4

I know this has been posted on here multiple times and on other sites.
I've been at this for days, tried everything from; reinstalling phpstorm, editing the php.ini file to uncomment extension=mysqli, etc.
I'm using php storm. My configurations are File: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.exe
My interpreter is php 7.4.1 and the php.ini file is stored in C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini

Everyone I know never had this problem. I've installed my phpstorm fresh again and it's still happening. I'm on windows, there's no problems with my PC. I don't know what to do, please help me. Thank you

Comment: Check you have the `extension=php_mysqli` enabled in your `php.ini`

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the correct INI file? How did you know that this is the correct path? CLI and web version have different INIs usually

Comment: RiggsFolly, thanks, it wasn't in there. Only extension=mysqli was. I added it in and still the same error :/

Comment: Are you sure you have mysqli DLL in your PHP release? Did you check PHP error log?

Comment: Dharman I didn't know this. How do I find the right ini?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-to-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line

Comment: How do i check php error log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: If you have secondary questions then I recommend Google. All I did is copied your comment into Google and pasted the link to the topmost result.

Comment: @Dharman is php -- ini supposed to be inputted into my terminal?? I'm looking at the link you sent

Comment: If you are using PHP cli then run `php --ini` else follow the other suggestions

Comment: what do you mean run ```php --ini``` run on what? do i type ```php --ini``` somewhere?