# Command-line PHP is using multiple ini files

Tags: php, composer-php, php-ini

I was trying to install a composer package and ran this command: `php composer.phar require phpmailer/phpmailer`. The response included this:

> Failed to download phpmailer/phpmailer from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
> Your command-line PHP is using multiple ini files. Run `php --ini` to show them.
> Now trying to download from source

Infact the package did download from source. I need to work out how to get unzipping to work but I also want to try and understand about the multiple ini files and what to do about it. I ran the command: `php --ini`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-72:/var/www/html$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

I would like to know more about what to do about this situation. I thought that PHP could use more than one ini file.

**Edit**

It was suggested that [Where can I find php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini) and [How can I find the php.ini file used by the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750580/how-can-i-find-the-php-ini-file-used-by-the-command-line) contained answers to my question but they do not. I am questioning why, in the context of a warning relating to a failed PHP command, I was informed that

> [my] command-line PHP is using multiple ini files

I want to know why this was mentioned in relation to the failed PHP command I issued and whether I need to do something about it and if so what I should do.

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` or use `php -i` and check the console for (*Loaded Configuration File =>*).  apart from those links

Comment: Each file is read in alphabetical order (that why `20-` prefix) and overwrites previous set config or adds new ones.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your helpful comments. Is it actually a problem? The message I got implies it is a problem but is not explicit about that.